# Recognize and tag mp3s

Tags: music, mp3

Are there any Android applications which will recognize my mp3s from a directory and tag them automatically?

Some of my mp3s have wrong file names and tags. I want to organize them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many PC apps that will do this. You could simply plug your phone into your computer, mount the SD card, and configure the app to search the sd card.

I haven't tried this myself, but I found an app on the market called [DroiID3Tagger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.booleancorp) that appears to automatically tag mp3s. There are plenty of others that allow you to edit the tags manually.

Comment: Could please let me know some good PC apps which can do this? Thanks in advance...